# Not Respond to Twilio Webhook Node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio

How can I respond to a twilio post request webhook without sending back the user a message? I have a use case where, when I receive a user message through my twilio webhook, I don't want to respond right away. Presumbably I need to respond to the post request, so is there any way I can respond to the request while preventing a message from being sent to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should respond with empty TwiML.

A response without anything nested under it.

Comment: Yes, your response seems correct... https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/sms-webhooks

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you are handling sms message and doesn't want to respond to the message immediately.

In this case, you can simply return 200 Ok to the incoming webhook message.

For node express server, you can return by

```
res.sendstatus(200)
```

You can find more details here - http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus

Comment: I think it should be `res.sendStatus`

Comment: Upon further testing, I don't think this works. Twilio is transposing the "ok" status into a message with "OK" as the body...